# Sybase to Oracle table move

Tags: oracle, migration, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration, sybase

I want to move tables from my sybase database to my oracle database. However, some tables in my sybase database have long identifiers or table names (above 30chars) so the "copy to oracle" function on Oracle SQL Developer keeps failing.

How can I migrate TABLE DATA only to my oracle schema?
Also note, I tired doing the data migration flow but when i get to the step to move data, it doesn't let me move table data. It just isn't visible. It'll only let me move procedures and such. 
Do i have something disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable long identifiers in your 12cR2 (12.2.x.y) or newer version of Oracle Database.

As soon as you set COMPATIBLE to “12.2.0” or higher for your Database, you can use the Long identifiers for every object in Oracle with the following exceptions:

- Database name ≤ 8 byte
- Disk groups ≤ 30 byte
- PDB names ≤ 30 byte
- Rollback segments ≤ 30 byte
- Tablespace names ≤ 30 byte
- Tablespace sets ≤ 30 byte

So let's do a table then...I'm running 12.2 in this scenario, but it would be find in 18c or 19c as well.

[image]

Click OK and I get - Success!

```
Copied Objects:
Sybase.copy_to_oracle.dbo.TABLE.this_is_a_table_to_hold_employees_please_dont_put_customers_in_it
Drop Target: HR
Copy DDL: Yes
Do Not Replace Existing Objects
Copy Data: Yes
Append Existing Objects
Task Succeeded.

1 table(s) copied.
    Created table this_is_a_table_to_hold_employees_please_dont_put_customers_in_it and inserted 0 row(s)
```

Comment: Note, if you are using the Migration wizard, there is an option to enable 12c features which includes extended identifiers, if this isn't enabled, we'll truncate the object names down to first 30 characters when doing the migration for your schema(s).

Comment: Yeah, I was using the Migration wizard. It created the CREATE table scripts for me but i can get the inserts for the tables. It wont generate anything in the datamove folder.

Comment: you're asking 2 separate questions, i chose to answer the Copy to Oracle and 30 character long portion. suggest you start a new question with the details of your migration project issue